# PySimpleGUI How to make font background color in the combo element the same when a defaut value is chosen (theme background color)

Tags: pysimplegui

I can't make the text background in the combo element stay the same as theme backgound and not turn white when an option been chosen, I'm fine when the backgound color turn white in the dropdown. It's no big deal, it just ticks me off.

[image: Here's when the script just lauched] [image: Here's when you select something]

```
sg.Combo(stat_history, font=('Helvetica', background_color=sg.theme_background_color()), readonly=True, default_value='Week', key='-stat_history-')
```

I tried edit the font argument but the iterpreter throws an error, says syntax error, pylance says "(" was not closed, here-> font=(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you find that you can set `font` with value `background_color` ?

```py
font=('Helvetica', background_color=sg.theme_background_color())
```

Be sure you write the code based on provided document.

The colors are different for default value and clicked value, and it is caused by the text selected after you click one item in a Combo element.

You can change it by select the text after window finaized.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

lst = ['Day', 'Week', 'Month', 'Year']
layout = [[sg.Combo(lst, font=('Helvetica', 11), size=20, readonly=True, default_value='Week', key='-COMBO-')]]
window = sg.Window("Title", layout, finalize=True)

# Set `select all` for default value
element = window['-COMBO-']
element.widget.select_range(0, sg.tk.END)     # After window finalized

# Set colors of foreground and background in entry field of Combo element.
style = sg.ttk.Style()
style_name = window['-COMBO-'].widget.configure()['style'][-1]
style.configure(style_name, selectforeground=sg.theme_input_text_color())
style.configure(style_name, selectbackground=sg.theme_input_background_color())

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break

window.close()
```

Or, you can remove the selection

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

lst = ['Day', 'Week', 'Month', 'Year']
layout = [[sg.Combo(lst, font=('Helvetica', 11), size=20, enable_events=True, readonly=True, default_value='Week', key='-COMBO-')]]
window = sg.Window("Title", layout, finalize=True)

element = window['-COMBO-']

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == '-COMBO-':
        element.widget.select_clear()

window.close()
```

Comment: Well in the documentation and in vs code it says font: specifies font family, size, etc.. idk what else etc. is supposed to mean. And your widget.select_range did exactly the opposite :) It's always white now, I need background color

Comment: I managed to make it grey, with enabling events in the event loop I did widget.select_range(0,0), the only problem is that it flashed for a brief moment when I select an option. How Can I get rid of the flashing now? Update: I tested and there's no flashing if you don't set timeout, but in my app theres a timeout=100

Comment: Updated as above.

Comment: Latest on GitHub doesn't highlight if `readonly=True` when making the Combo in your layout.

Comment: They still look different for text-selected or text-not-selected entry, maybe not about `readonly=True` or `readonly=False`.

Comment: Perhaps set the ttk theme to `'alt'` if want to do it without having to get events.